# How do I use a COM object from C?

Tags: c, com, dll

I have a DLL containing a COM object that I'm trying to use.
I couldn't find any good explanations of how to do so with C.
It would be much appreciated if you guys could redirect me to a tutorial or something.

Answer (score 1):

[Code project](http://codeproject.com) has a lot of samples. A quick search gave me [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_in_c1.aspx) article on COM in C.

Answer (score 1):

Writing C code that uses a COM server is outlawed by the 'cruel and unusual punishment' clause in Article 5 of the Universal Declaration of Human Rights.

Should you elect to ignore this then try to get started by running OleView.exe, File + View TypeLib, select the DLL.  That opens a window with the contents of the type library embedded in the DLL.  Copy and paste the interface declarations into a .idl file.  Run this through midl.exe, that produces a .h file that has C compatible declarations for the interfaces.

Comment: Eh, it's not _that_ much worse than C++. Apart from all the manual reference count juggling, that is. It's not nearly as bad as writing a COM _server_ in C, that's for sure...

Comment: Getting the interface declarations is the problem.  *Writing* a COM server in C is actually simpler.